# Why is IIS bypassing OnException error handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

All my controllers inherit from `BaseController`, which includes the following method to support logging of errors and suitable redirects:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
    {
        return;
    }

    LogException(filterContext.Exception);

    if (filterContext.Exception is PermissionException)
    {
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized", "Home");
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
    else
    {
#if !DEBUG
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
#endif
    }
}
```

However, IIS never reaches the line `LogException`.  How can I configure IIS to allow the method to process in the same way it does in my development environment? I'm also open to other methods of logging errors in my db.

Comment: The ExceptionHandled is a value you can change. You are overriding and the value comes in as true. You need to determine if you are going to handle it or not.

Comment: Exception has already been handled and that is the reason logException is not getting hit. I am not sure but can you use ELMAH?

Comment: If so, then what is causing `ExceptionHandled` to be true on deployed IIS and false in dev environment?

Comment: Could be you have a global filter registered or have an attribute like HandleError somewhere that's handling the error first.